# 3D projectile motion simulator with drag is not constrained to a 2D plane

Tags: computational-physics, projectile, simulations, drag, software

This is an example of the problem. I've set the initial velocities to be $(x,y,z) = (100,10,100)$ and the drag-coefficient and CS-area to be 1.

[image]

As you can see the motion is not constrained to one plane. However if I remove the drag force by setting the coefficient to 0, I get a constrained graph.

Here are some parts of the code (Python) which should, in theory, contain the error. I'm using the Euler integration method.

```
...
...
class Fluid:
    def __init__(self, density:float, dragCoefficient:float):
        self.density = density
        self.dragCoefficient = dragCoefficient
    def fluidResitanceForce(self, crossSectionalArea:float, velocity:float):
        if velocity>=0:
            return -0.5*self.density*self.dragCoefficient*crossSectionalArea*velocity**2
        else: 
            return 0.5*self.density*self.dragCoefficient*crossSectionalArea*velocity**2
...
...
class Simulator:
    ...
    ...
    def forceComputer(self):
        currentForces = np.array([
            self.Fluid.fluidResitanceForce(self.Object.crossSectionalArea, self.Object.velocity[0]),
            self.Fluid.fluidResitanceForce(self.Object.crossSectionalArea, self.Object.velocity[1]),
            self.Fluid.fluidResitanceForce(self.Object.crossSectionalArea, self.Object.velocity[2])-self.Object.mass*self.gravity
        ])
        self.Object.setForce(currentForces)
    
    def compute(self):
        while True:
            self.time += self.deltaTime
            self.forceComputer()
            self.Object.position = self.Object.position + self.deltaTime*self.Object.velocity
            self.Object.velocity = self.Object.velocity + self.deltaTime*self.Object.acceleration
            self.history["positionHistory"].append(self.Object.position)
            self.history["velocityHistory"].append(self.Object.velocity)
            self.history["timeHistory"].append(self.deltaTime)
...
...
```

I'd very much appreciate some advice on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the fluid resistance is wrong. You're computing this component-wise, but splitting up a computation on a vector into separate calculation on each cartesian component is only valid for linear operations. The drag equation is not linear, it's quadratic. Only for the case constrained to one dimension can it be written
$$
  F_\mathrm{d} = -\tfrac12\cdot\rho\cdot c_\mathrm{d}\cdot A\cdot v^2
$$
For vectorial movement, you should interpret it instead as
$$
  \mathbf{F}_\mathrm{d} = -\tfrac12\cdot\rho\cdot c_\mathrm{d}\cdot A\cdot \|\mathbf v\|\cdot \mathbf{v}
$$
i.e. the drag always points in opposing direction to the current movement.

Do it like this, and you also won't need the case distinction on `velocity>=0`.

---

Some comments, not really concerning what the question asked:

You're using the numerical technique called [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) here. That's ok for this application as long as you keep the time step small enough, but do note that it is not really a good method, having both low accuracy and being unstable. Don't make it a habit to throw this on every problem, read up on [Runge-Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods). (Euler is 1st-order Runge-Kutta, but higher-order ones are generally better.)

You've split your problem into multiple classes, but then do the actual maths regardless in `Simulator`. If you're going to go OO, you should do it consequently and have the object perform its own updates and force calculations.
However, you'll find that this paradigm is not really the most convenient for physics simulations, specifically when you want to go to higher-order solvers. OO is good for discrete, mutable updates (which happens to be what the Euler method does), but not so much for abstracting over higher-order methods. If you do this in OO, you should instead have abstractions like `ODESolver` and `SimulationState`, where the former does computations on the latter without knowing what physics it simulates. IMO, this is actually much nicer to express in a [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) style, rather than OO.

Comment: Thanks- that makes sense!